# redmine email notifications with my own postfix server

Tags: smtp, redmine, postfix-mta

I can't get redmine's email notifications to work. I am running my own mailserver with postfix using some mysql backend for the accounts. I added an account for redmine and tested it successfully using thunderbird. It is configured on port 25 using STARTTLS.

This is my `config/configuration.yml` of redmine:

```
production:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      tls: true
      address: www.mydomain.org
      port: 25
      authentication: :login
      domain: mydomain.org
      user_name: tracker@mydomain.org
      password: PASSWORD
```

As I said, the credentials work for sure. The port is 25 and the `address` is correct as well. Redmine is running on the same server, but using `localhost` as `address` doesn't work either.

The error message redmine is giving me reads

```
... (Connection timed out - connect(2)).
```

In the postfix log files, I can find nothing, not even an attempt to login or send an email. I am using `Ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 3xx` and `Rails 2.3.5`. It seems like there is a problem with the connection in general, and not with my mailserver.

What can I do to find the source of the problem? I am not very familiar with how ruby works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out... Below the commented, suggested configuration blocks in the `configuration.xml` file is another, uncommented email block, that reads

```
default:
    email_delivery: ...
```

Even though I thought that by uncommenting the `production:` block these settings would be overridden, it started working the moment I inserted the email settings into this `default` block. This is a bit weird, but anyway - it does work now like a charm.